# Construct CAMetalLayer from CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: ios, metal

I have created a `CVPixelBufferRef` and I am using a 3rd party rendering engine that expects a `CAMetalLayer` as its render target.

Is it possible to construct `CAMetalLayer` for my `CVPixelBufferRef`?

Comment: You'll need to render or blit the contents of the pixel buffer into the layer's drawable. As far as I know, there's no way to associate the contents of pixel buffer with a Metal layer such that updating the contents of the pixel buffer automatically updates the contents of the layer.

Comment: I need the other way round. All painting onto the CAMetalLayer should be going into the pixelbuffer.

Comment: In that case, you could wrap your pixel buffer in a Metal texture, then have the third-party engine render into a layer whose `framebufferOnly` property is set to `NO`, then blit from the layer's current drawable's texture into the pixel buffer-backed texture.